# Run HDFS command as EMR Step

Tags: hdfs, emr

How can I issue an `hdfs` command as a step in an EMR cluster? Adding the step as a `script_runner.jar` task seems to fail oddly.

Answer (score 6):

Use `command-runner.jar` and call out to `bash` to issue your `hdfs` command.

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXXXXXX --steps Name="Command Runner",Jar="command-runner.jar",Args=[/bin/bash,-c,"\"hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp/foo\""]
```

Note that the final argument is passed as one single escape quoted string to `bash`.